# Why would this EF scenario NOT lazy load a child entity?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a simple controller method (via ajax) that inserts a new entity into the db and then queries the database for all of the same type of records and returns a list of those records(json).

What I can't figure out is that when I insert the first record and query for my list of records, any child entities are not lazy loaded.  However, when I add a second or any number of subsequent records my list includes all child entities lazy loaded as expected.  Here is some code:

```
public class Person
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int StateId {get;set;}
  public virtual State State {get;set;}
} 

public class PersonController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult CreatePerson(PersonModel model)
  {
    var person = model.ToPersonEntity();
    _personService.InsertPerson(person);

    var people = _personService.GetAllPeople();//on first person inserted this list does NOT have State loaded
    var personAddresssList = people.Select(x => x.ToPersonAddressFormat());

    return Json(personAddressList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

There isn't really any more relevant code as this is a pretty simple operation.  I fixed the problem by using .Include(x => x.State) in my linq query but I've never had to do this as long as my properties were marked 'Virtual'.

The only thing I can think of is that EF still has my original person as a tracked entity and that when I pull up the list of persons and the only person is the one I just inserted, it uses the cached entity which would not have any child properties attached to it yet.  If this is true then when I load a list of more than one person, some funky black magic in EF says "I see 2 items in the list I won't use the cached person I just inserted".

Any ideas?

Comment: does the function `model.ToPersonEntity();` new up an entity or use `context.Set<Person>().Create()`? Using the `Create()` method may resolve your problem.

Comment: It creates a new person and maps the model to the person.  That's it.

Comment: I get that but does it use the `new` keyword? If you use `context.Set<Person>().Create()` you'll get a proxied instance which will have all of the lazy loading features that are missing from the new'ed up version.

Comment: Yes. However, this isn't what my issue is.  I am only missing the child entity after(and only) creating the FIRST person.  When I create the SECOND, THIRD, etc. person my list has all child entities lazy loaded as expected.